# multirow, multicolumns and cell width

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

I am trying to build a table like this one

[image]

But so far I only arrive to this

```
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{center}
\scalebox{0.93}{\sffamily
\begin{tabular}{ |p{1cm}|p{1.cm}|p{1.9cm}|p{10.7cm}|}
\hline
\rowcolor{gray|30}{\color{white}Grado} & {\color{white}\'Indice} &      {\color{white}Pa\'ises} & {\color{white}Descripci\'on}\\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{A} & \multirow{2}{*}{> 80} & Dinamarca P\'aises Bajos & Un    sistema de pensiones robusto y de primera clase que proporciona buenas   prestaciones, es sostenible y tiene un elevado nivel de integridad\\ \hline
 B+ & 75-80 & Australia & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\multirow{7}{*}{Sistema que tiene una estructura con buenas caracter\'isticas pero tiene \'areas de mejora que lo diferencia de los sistemas con grado A}} \\ \cmidrule{1-3}
 \multirow{6}{*}{B} & \multirow{6}{*}{65-75} & Suecia & \\
  & & Suiza & \\
  & & Finlandia & \\
  & & Canad\'a & \\
  & & Chile & \\
  & & Reino Unido & \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}}
  \end{center}
```

I have problems at the time of combining the rows and at the time of define the width of the longest cell.

Thanks for your support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not very clear what is your problem. According to image I suggest to make the following  small changes:

- not use `scalebox`, instead it use `tabularx`
- content  of multi lines `multirow` cell enclose in `parbox` or `minipage`
- with vertical lines not use reles provided by package `booktabs`

Considering above your code can be rewrite into the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow,tabularx}

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |p{1cm}|p{1.cm}|p{2cm}|X|}
    \hline
\rowcolor{gray}\textcolor{white}{Grado} 
    &   \textcolor{white}{\'Indice} 
        &  \textcolor{white}{Pa\'ises} 
            &   \textcolor{white}{Descripci\'on}        \\
    \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{A} 
    & \multirow{2}{*}{> 80} 
        & Dinamarca P\'aises Bajos 
            &   Un sistema de pensiones robusto y de primera clase que proporciona buenas   prestaciones, es sostenible y tiene un elevado nivel de integridad\\
    \hline
 B+ &   75-80 
        &   Australia 
            &   \multirow{7}*{\parbox{\hsize}{
                Sistema que tiene una estructura con buenas caracter\'isticas pero tiene \'areas de mejora que lo diferencia de los sistemas con grado A
                                }}                       \\ \cline{1-3}
\multirow{6}{*}{B} 
    &   \multirow{6}{*}{65-75} 
        &   Suecia      &   \\
    &   &   Suiza       &   \\
    &   &   Finlandia   &   \\
    &   &   Canad\'a    &   \\
    &   &   Chile       &   \\
    &   &   Reino Unido &   \\ 
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]